# Can $\mathbb{Q×Q}$ be embedded in $\mathbb{R}$ as group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

I think ans is NO : if possible let that is true hence there is a monomorphism from $H= \mathbb{Q×Q}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.  as $\mathbb{R} $ has only subgroups which is cyclic or dense and $H$ is not cyclic hence dense but it's proper subgroup 
 $\mathbb{Z×Z}$ is neither cyclic nor  dense in $\mathbb{R}$ hence contradiction.  Hence the claim.

Is my proof correct??
Thanks.

Comment: How do you know $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ is not dense in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Try $(a,b)\mapsto a+b\sqrt2$.

Comment: Your proof is incorrect. While you claim to have derived a contradiction, you did not actually arrive at any contradiction. Note that while $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$ may not be dense within $\Bbb Q\times\Bbb Q$ with the product topology, that doesn't mean its isomorphic copy in $\Bbb R$ isn't dense.

Comment: If you know that $\mathbb{R}$ is an infinite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ then the answer is trivially yes.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with topology—only the algebraic structures of the groups—so arguments about density are unlikely to be relevant.

Comment: @trisct I know that but from that how the answer is trivially yes?

Comment: it is like embedding $\mathbb{Q}^2$ into $\mathbb{R}\cong\mathbb{Q}^\infty$. Lord Shark the Unknown's answer is an example of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $(a,b)\mapsto a+b\sqrt2$ is an injection $\mathbb{Q×Q} \to \mathbb{R}$ because $\sqrt2$ is irrational.

$\sqrt2$ is not special here; any irrational number works, for instance $\pi$.

Comment: Based on a comment by Lord Shark the Unknown.

Answer (score 7):

Let $\{e_i: i \in I\}$ be a basis for the vector space of $\Bbb R$ over the field $\Bbb Q$. It is clear from cardinality considerations that $I$ is uncountable.

Pick any two distinct elements from the base, say $e_{i_1}$ and $e_{i_2}$. 
Map $(q,q') \in \Bbb Q^2$ to $qe_{i_1} + q'e_{i_2} \in \Bbb R$ and note that we have group embedding.

This of course works for any finite power of the rationals.